# df -h says / fs is taking 61G of space but its not

Tags: linux, redhat, ext4, rhel7, df

df -h in my redhat 7 is reporting its taking 61G of space. This should be wrong because there shouldn't be anything there which is this big. Other server with the same configuration reports only 11G.

[Output of df -h:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxz4A.png)

[Output of du -sh /*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP1bR.png)

Maximum space is consumed by /var and thats only 11g. I checked all the files and directories inside /var but couldn't find anything big.

Please Advise,

Comment: Did you check for open but deleted files?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted files that are used by processes are not deleted from the filesystem until they are released. (this is a feature in Linux)

Check

```
# lsof|grep "(deleted)"
```

Kill the process using some large files (log files?) to free the disk space. (of course you have to face the consequencies)

If you tried reboot then this is not the case for sure.

+1: If you use filesystem (for example btrfs, zfs) there might be snapshots using space but not mounted.

Comment: I have rebooted this server many times but no luck. I do see some deleted files with lsof like these:
sssd        700                 root   16r      REG              253,1   10406312   68417395 /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups (deleted)

Comment: You can start to examine disk usage per directory starting with `du -sh /* /.*`, and then "drill down". There may exist nice graphical tools, too. If you cannot find such a big file, your filesystem might need checking and/or repairing.